# Where to put Stored Procedures & Swapping DB Tech?

Tags: sql, database, architecture

IS THIS ABSOLUTELY BONKERS.....

I have just started working on a new project and I'm shocked at what I have just seen. This project is a C# web app that sits on top of an Oracle database. Now all the stored procedures are not actually stored procedures.... They are just SQL scripts stored in text files in a directory on the server. When the application starts it looks in the directory and goes through each file and reading out the text and saving it in a dictionary. It also runs a Regex over the text removing special sequences like [PARAM] and replaces them with the correct symbol e.g. ':' in Oracles case or '@' for SQL SERVER. Then when the code wants to execute one of these statements it calls a method which finds the correct one in the dictionary and runs it.

Now this appears to have been done in case they ever wanted to swap underlying db technologies. They say they would just swap the sql files out of the directory for files in the appropriate syntax and it would work.

Now I would normally expect the stored procedures to be actually stored procedures and live on the db. A separate project (layer) that talks to the db.  Then if the db technology changes just add another data layer project and swap the dlls out....

I see massive problems with the way its been done currently:

- No execution plan on the db server being created.
- Massive overhead reading hundreds of text files, building up a string for each, running regex over it.
- No checking of SQL syntax.
- Big memory foot print having all these stored procedures in memory

What do you lot think?

Is this really bad or am I just moaning because I have never seen anything like this before?

What else is wrong with this approach?

Any comments will be much appreciated as I'm trying to get across to colleagues that this is crazy....

Comment: I have seen a fair few solutions to making the database agnostic when stored procedures and database logic is still required. Each and every example of this is a poster-child for YAGNI... no one has ever changed the database. I've seen something like this before, but not with conversion between the database providers. Aside from the caching point, I have to initially agree with all your concerns. Plus maintenance and getting something added to this must be a job and a half.

Comment: leigh - my 'heart' goes out to you. as adam above mentioned, this is a solution (albeit very weak) looking for a problem. there's no optimisation going on, there's a severe risk in play insofaras drive failure (granted, there will be backups??). all in all, whoever dreamt up this scenario ought to be quiverring in their 'bunker' as you are no doubt gonna seek them out on a regular basis when things just don't work as expected. good luck (and yes -BONKERS)!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do you lot think?

I think it's a classic case of over-engineering: who changes their DB provider? Is it **really** bringing anything to the table?

> Is this really bad or am I just moaning because I have never seen
>   anything like this before?

A bit of both in my opinion: it's quite bad but if they've been running like this for some time it's got to be working.

> What else is wrong with this approach?

As it is, re-calculating the execution plan every time is probably the biggest issue:
so much performance loss! I'm saying *probably* because performance is not always a requirement (over-optimization isn't any better ;)
**What is really wrong is that they reinvented the wheel: LINQ does that natively.**
And that means as LINQ gets improved over time, the company will steadily fall behind since they won't benefit from the enhancements.

If you have any leverage power, try to talk to them about LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't they use the scripts at build time to create stored procedure scripts in the native syntax (PSQL, T-SQL), which can then be deployed to the database? I can't see that would too much more work, and you get all the benefits of compiled stored procedure code etc.

I have personal experience of run-time compilation of stored procedures (SQL Server) being a big performance overhead, and on a production system this was a real problem.

I can sort of see the reasoning behind this design:

- Stored procedure code is too database specific, so we won't use
  stored procedures, we will use SQL statements instead.
- Even SQL statements can have database specific syntax in them, so
  we'll have some hokey method for converting them on the fly at
  run-time.

Even if you don't use stored procedures, I still think the conversion should be done at build time (e.g., to generate C# code), not run-time.